# How to get a base64-encoded SVG filter to work in other browsers than Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, filter

I have this SVG file with a filter I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow. It looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<filter id="white-glow" x="-5000%" y="-5000%" width="10000%" height="10000%">
<feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#ffaaa0" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
<feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
<feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
<feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
<feMerge>
<feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
</feMerge>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

CSS-loader (I'm using a Vue/Webpack setup) converts it to a base64 string that looks like this:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

I have it declared in my scoped CSS like so:

```
filter: url(../assets/filters.svg#white-glow);
```

Which, when building, CSS-loader turns into this:

```
filter: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64...#white-glow);
```

This works in Firefox 47, but not in Chrome 70 or Opera 56.

How do I solve this?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue terminology, but you should aim to position the filter inline in the page. In React, I would say make it a component.

Comment: Vue works with components as well. I had it that way before, but then it would only work in the '/' or root directory, because it would point to:
    filter: url(/#white-glow);
but on any other route (/about, /contact etc) it wouldn't work because it would still point to the root. Changing it in the inspector to say /about#white-glow would fix it again, but then every route would need its own filter declaration. Having it as static asset seemed to make sense since the asset would be contained in the CSS. But that only works in Firefox.

Comment: If the filter is inline, you would reference it as `url(#white-glow)`, without any server route. Where does that dash come from?

Comment: I added the preceding dash because it wouldn't work otherwise. I don't know why that is.

Comment: "It wouldn't work" is not a helpful description. Your setup is running through three completely different layers of execution: first, compilation with webpack, second, building of the webpage with Vue, and thirdly rendering by the browser. For stage three, your page needs to have that filter as an inline `<svg>` element, and a reference to its contained `<filter>` element id without any preceding dash. Where in the process do things go wrong?